# Как добавить стили конкретной вкладке с помощью расширения Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Здравствуйте.
Вот так добавляю стили, но они автоматически добавляются для всех страниц перечисленных в манифесте.

Как добавить css *конкретной* вкладке: через манифест или программно?

1. через манифест:

   ```
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "www.site1.ru/*", "site2.ru/*"],
   "content_scripts": [{ "matches": ["www.site1.ru/javascript/*", "site2.ru/javascript/*"],
      "css": ["css/my_style.css"],
      "js": ["content_scripts.js"] 
    }],
   ```
2. программно: из content_scripts.js, так у меня не работает:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null,{file:"css/my_style.css"});
   ```

   так тоже:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"' });
   ```

Comment: Не добавляйте метку `plugin`. В этом вопросе она не имеет смысла.

Comment: подключение CSS  в расширениях, и плагинах как то отличаются?

Comment: У Chrome не плагины, а расширения. Поэтому метка `plugin` не имеет смысла. У вас уже стоит метка [tag:chrome-extension]

Comment: цитата: У Chrome не плагины, а расширения.  Ок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите устанавливать стили в зависимости от условий, каких-то критериев или основываясь на содержимом странцы, то используйте программное добавление.

В строках

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null,{file:"css/my_style.css"});
```

и

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"' });
```

Вы не указываете параметр `tabId`.

> The ID of the tab in which to run the script; defaults to the active
>   tab of the current window.

Из-за этого код будет выполнятеся для текущей активной вкладки, а не в конкретно определенной вами вкладке.

Можете воспользоваться функцией `query`.

Эта функция вернет все вкладки удовлетворяющие заданными вами критериями.

Например вкладки с заданным заголовком страницы, активную или не активную, статусом, url и т п.

Полный список параметров перечислен [здесь](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query).

Прочтите [Programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi)

Можно сделать предположение, что вы вызываете функции `executeScript` и `insertCSS` из

```
"content_scripts": [{ "matches": ["www.site1.ru/javascript/\*", "site2.ru/javascript/\*"],
   "css": ["css/my_style.css"],
   "js": ["content_scripts.js"] 
 }]
```

=> `content_scripts.js`

В таком случае они работать точно не будут, потому что

> Here are some examples of what content scripts can do:
>
> - Find unlinked URLs in web pages and convert them into hyperlinks
> - Increase the font size to make text more legible
> - Find and process microformat data in the DOM However, content scripts    have some limitations.
>
> They cannot:
>
> Use chrome.* APIs, with the exception of:
>
> - extension ( getURL , inIncognitoContext , lastError , onRequest ,    sendRequest )
> - i18n
> - runtime ( connect , getManifest , getURL , id , onConnect , onMessage    , sendMessage )
> - storage
>
> Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages Use
>   variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content
>   scripts

Т.е content_scripts не может использовать функционал `chrome.tabs.api*`.

Если вам нужно воспользоватся этим функционалом, то нужно вынести код в `background` скрипт.

В manifest.json

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["script.js"]
}
```

И действия с вкладками выполняйте в нем.

Прочтите про [Execution environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment)

Comment: Так и есть вызываю из: content_scripts.js.  
Вы привели ссылки: спасибо, но они несильно помогут так как с английским не очень.

Comment: @Макс, воспользуйтесь [переводчиком](https://translate.google.com/), смысл будет ясен. Вы уже можете отталкиватся от того что я написал вам в ответе.

Comment: Можно ли решить задачу для sontent_script: используя getURL();       var css = chrome.extension.getURL("css/my_style.css");

Comment: Cкрипт  <script src="content_scripts.js"></script> таким образом добавил, CSS так же добавляется в консолье видно, но для страницы не применяется, возможно потому что DOM построен

Comment: @Макс, я ничего не понял.
 <script src="content_scripts.js"></script> что это? Зачем вам это?

Comment: Можно ли решить задачу из файла: sontent_script.js  используя getURL(); var css = chrome.extension.getURL("css/my_style.css");  Для добавления скриптов для данной вкладки = подобную задачу решил. Таким образом добавил, CSS так же добавляется в консолье видно, но для страницы не применяется, возможно потому что DOM построен

Comment: @Макс, добавить стили на конкретную вкладку из content_scripts? Речь об этом?

Comment: Да, добавить стили из content_scripts, он собственно и работает с этой вкладкой.

Comment: @Макс, я уже писал, что работать с вкладками нельзя из content_scripts. Перейдите по ссылкам что я дал и прочитайте. Используйте переводчик. Из `content_scripts` вы можете искать нужные элементы на страницах, которые вы в `matches` указали и добавлять им стили. Что-то вроде `window.onload = function () {var elem = document.getElementById("elem"); elem.style.background = "red";};`. Тут после загрузки страницы происходит поиск элемента на странице с id 'elem' и позже устанавливаются стили. Но это в пределах страницы.

Comment: Ок, спасибо вам.